# Who must give Udhiyyah?

Tags: eid, udhiyyah

According to sunnis, who must give Udhiyyah?  i.e. do you have to have a certain amount of money before you can give Udhiyyah?  Must you be of a certain age?

Comment: This is several questions asked as one question. Perhaps breaking them off into multiple questions would make more sense; is your core question about the conditions of udhiyyah?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uddhyah is Wajib in the Hanafi school, it is required on

1. A Muslim, it is not required on a Kafir
2. On a Free person
3. On a non-traveling one, it is not required on a traveler
4. On a Rich person, it is not required on a poor person

It is a must to eat from the udhiyyah, as well as it is a must to feed the poor and the rich  from the meat.  The best thing to do is split it up into three parts, give one part as sadaqah, keep one part for himself and his family, and the other part to his close relatives and friends.  If he gives all of the meat as sadaqah, than that is the best.  If he kept all of it than it is  ( i am not sure if ok is the word, in Arabic it is {Jaaz})

Source: [Al-Fiqh Al Muyassar on the school of the greatest Imam Abu Hanafa Anna'man](http://kitaabun.com/shopping3/product_info.php?manufacturers_id=34&products_id=2980&osCsid=b0d)

Comment: Any chance of defining "a Rich person".  What exactly does that mean, how much wealth must you have to be classified as a "Rich person" for Udhiyyah purposes?

Comment: Ditto for a "free" person.